# Object getting updated automatically without any assignemnt

Tags: c#, class, object, data-structures, binary-tree

I made a simple program in C# to add a node in binary tree.
I have an object field 'Root' to hold the main parent Node. such that every time I add a node I traverse from the tree by retrieving the data in Parent Node.

Here is my code

```
public class BTNode
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }        
        public BTNode Left { get; set; }
        public BTNode Right { get; set; }
        public BTNode Root { get; set; }
   }


public class BinaryTree
   {
       public  BinaryTree()
        {
            size = 0;
            Root = null; //To hold the main Parent Node
         }
        int size;
        object Root;

        public void AddNode(int value)
        {
            BTNode NewNode = new BTNode();
            if (Root != null)
            {
                NewNode = (BTNode)Root; //If tree exists, Get the Root Node
            }

            while (NewNode.Root != null)
            {
                if (value < NewNode.Value)
                {
                    NewNode.Root = NewNode.Left;
                }
                else if (value > NewNode.Value)
                {
                    NewNode.Root = NewNode.Right;
                }
            }

            size++;
            NewNode.Value = value;   //OBJECT 'ROOT' GETTING UPDATED AT THIS POINT
            NewNode.Root = NewNode;  //self pointer 
            NewNode.Left = null;
            NewNode.Right = null;

            if (size == 1)
            {
                Root = (object) NewNode;  //if this is the Parent Node(First Node) 
            }                             //then update the Root to be the parent Node
        }
    }
```

I want to hold only parent node of the Binary Tree in 'Root'.. I only want to execute the last line when size =1 i.e if its the first node of the tree but no matter what I do the Root gets updated for every node. I am struggling to know why this is happening, Please help me. am I missing any concpept, logic here.

Comment: When you say `NewNode.Root = NewNode.Left;` aren't you re-assigning the `Root` of each node?  I think instead you just want to say `NewNode = NewNode.Left;`

Comment: I actually created NewNode.Root so that I can use it as a reference or pointers to its child nodes. I think I can just code like u said. I wouldnt be needing the Root prperty in the BTNode class. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your `Root` property could be typed to `BTNode`. This way you wouldn't need to cast it
2. The line `NewNode = (BTNode)Root;` is getting the root node reference. Any change you make to `NewNode` will affect the root node. Are you aware of **value types** and **reference types**?
3. I don't understand why you're going *up* (checking for the `Root`) and not *down* (checking for the Left or Right nodes).

Check this solution, please. It uses a simple recursive method to place the new node:

```
public class BinaryTree
    {
        public BinaryTree()
        {
            size = 0;
            Root = null; //To hold the main Parent Node
        }
        int size;
        BTNode Root;

        public void AddNode(int value)
        {
            size++;
            BTNode NewNode = new BTNode()
            {
                Value = value
            };

            if (this.Root == null)
            {
                this.Root = NewNode;
                return;
            }

            this.PlaceNewNode(this.Root, NewNode);
        }

        public void PlaceNewNode(BTNode RootNode, BTNode NewNode)
        {
            if (NewNode.Value < RootNode.Value)
            {
                if (RootNode.Left != null)
                {
                    PlaceNewNode(RootNode.Left, NewNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    RootNode.Left = NewNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (RootNode.Right != null)
                {
                    PlaceNewNode(RootNode.Right, NewNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    RootNode.Right = NewNode;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: Thank you Andre. I actually tried root of the type BTNode first and then changed it to an object.
I needed the root node because I wanted the new node that is being added to the tree to compare from the root of the tree rather than comparing it from the last inserted node, so everytime I add a node I will be traversing from the root and inserting the node at the appropriate place. Thanks for your answer, will check it right now.

Comment: I understand, it's quite use to modify the code so you can keep the reference of the root as well. You are most welcome

Comment: @Rasm Follow up: please, don't forget to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your use of the word Root is confusing.  A tree can only have a single root object.  Node objects can have a parent node (unless its the root).  Tree structures lend themselves nicely to recursive code.

Here's some code that's similar to what Andre posted.

```
public class BTNode
{
    public BTNode() { }
    public BTNode(int value) { Value = value; }

    public int Value { get; set; }
    public BTNode Left { get; set; }
    public BTNode Right { get; set; }
    public BTNode Parent { get; set; }
}

public class BinaryTree
{
    public BinaryTree() { }

    public BTNode Root { get; private set; }
    public int Size { get; private set; }

    public void AddNode(int value)
    {
        BTNode insertNode = new BTNode(value);
        if (Root == null)
            Root = insertNode;
        else
            AddNodeToTree(Root, insertNode);
        Size++;
    }

    private void AddNodeToTree(BTNode parentNode, BTNode insertNode)
    {
        if (insertNode.Value >= parentNode.Value)
        {
            if (parentNode.Right != null)
                AddNodeToTree(parentNode.Right, insertNode);
            else
            {
                parentNode.Right = insertNode;
                insertNode.Parent = parentNode;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (parentNode.Left != null)
                AddNodeToTree(parentNode.Left, insertNode);
            else
            {
                parentNode.Left = insertNode;
                insertNode.Parent = parentNode;
            }
        }
    }

    public BTNode FindNode(int value)
    {
        return FindNode(Root, value);
    }

    public BTNode FindNode(BTNode parent, int value)
    {
        BTNode node = null;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            if (parent.Value == value)
                node = parent;
            else
            {
                if (parent.Value < value)
                    node = FindNode(parent.Right, value);
                else
                    node = FindNode(parent.Left, value);
            }
        }
        return node;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks mdm. I wanted to store the root of the binary tree and use that to traverse the tree whenever a new node is inserted. thanks for your solution. both of your code works.
I should have used another name for the property root in the BTNode class.